# TypeError: Required argument 'year' (pos 1) not found in django

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

I added a new field to my already existing model and when I run `python manage.py makemigrations` and I got the following

```
1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
 Select an option: 1
 Please enter the default value now, as valid Python
 The datetime and django.utils.timezone modules are available, so you can do e.g. timezone.now()
```

I accidentally run `>>timezone.date()`

Then when I run `python manage.py migrate` I get the following error

`TypeError: Required argument 'year' (pos 1) not found`

My following is my showmigrations

```
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_auto_20180307_1222
 [X] 0003_auto_20180308_1608
 [X] 0004_auto_20180421_0937
 [ ] 0005_auto_20180702_1917
 [ ] 0006_auto_20180702_1949
 [ ] 0007_auto_20180702_2000
```

How can I solve this problem.

Comment: just remove your undoing migrations (0005~0007) and makemigrations again

Comment: Can you please post the relevant part of your model code, relevant migration file?

Comment: Your model might require the year portion of datetime. timezone.now() sends back a datetime object. For a smooth model migrations, delete migrations 5,6,7 from migrations folder, add Default parameter with a value on the model... (use randint() function from random,) then use makemigrations, migrate.

Comment: it seems you add an integer field to your model named year. but in makemigration you set default value of this method to datetimeobject and its raise exception when running migration

Comment: Thanks guys I solved the problem by removing the file 5,6,7 and made migration and it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks guys I solved the problem by removing the file 5,6,7 and made migration and it worked